# Neo4j suggestion on large scale

Tags: neo4j, cypher

i need to implement a `suggestion` system for my project
in this system we should recommend people base on some parameters like current city, education, friend of friends etc.

i have designed this by creating(update) may_know relations when users edit their profile or become friend with someone and i will retrieve them by `MATCH u-[r:MAY_KNOW]-x RETURN * ORDER BY r.weight` so people can find most like people to them
but i think this is not a best practice because soon may_know relation from/to every user can reach even milions and scan and sorting them will be heavy cost

do you have a better idea?

Comment: Add a depth limit to the query (immediate friends = 1, friends of friends = 2, etc.)

Comment: probably start by limiting by the most discriminating factors? Where direct friends, city and education are more discriminating than friends-of-friend of level 2 or 3.

Comment: for example i put weight of being in same city = 1, so when a user choose his/city i will merge a may_know relation to every peaple on that city on create i will put weight = 1 otherwise i`ll increament weight value by one.
same for friends of friends(with weight 0.5) and field of study(with weight 2)
limiting suggestion to one factor is my last option
is there any other soloution?

Answer (score 0):

Depends a bit on the data-structure, I assume there are relationships to cities, education facilities and friends. So you don't actually have `MAY_KNOW` relationships as those are only inferred?

Also it depends if you want to create a cross products between all your users (how many) and how you would want to filter out non-related people.

Perhaps check out this blog post from Max: http://maxdemarzi.com/2013/04/19/match-making-with-neo4j/

So something like this query might work (depending on the data volume I'd rewrite it in the Java API).

```
match (p:Person {id:{user_id})
match (p)-[:LIVES_IN]->(:City)<-[:LIVES_IN]-(other)
match (p)-[:GRADUATED]->(:School)<-[:GRADUATED]-(other)
match (p)-[:KNOWS]->(:Person)<-[:KNOWS]-(other)
RETURN other
```